# How to insert new column into CSV in nodejs

Tags: node.js, csv, node-csv-parse

I have to add a new cell in each row. let's say I have a list of products CSV and I am fetching the image URL for each product it using some functionality and I need to update the URL corresponding to each product.

```
const writestream = fs.createWriteStream('src/working_file.csv', {
    flags: 'a'
  });
 writestream.write({ image: imageURL });
```

the "image" is the new column name I want in my CSV file. "imageURL" is the URL of the produc I have in my hand

the above code is giving *TypeError: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk*

I got to read the CSV also for some reasons and I am using [csv-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser) for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `imageURL` as a string, not an object containing the `imageURL`. You might need to append a comma as well to separate it from the other columns, depending on the format of your file:

```
writestream.write("," + imageURL);
```

Comment: this will add ,imageURL at the end of the file. but not at the end of the each line.

Comment: please edit the question and add all the relevant code, how am I supposed to know how you are writing each line.